# Java turtle graphics user input

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to write a turtle graphics program in Java. It needs to be able to create 2D graphics by reading commands inputted by the user through a JTextField. I have created the GUI and written the different methods for each command such as turnRight, turnLeft, forward etc however the issue I'm having is I've created an if/else statement with action listeners on the JTextField so that it may recognize the commands given by the user and have attempted to call the methods I've written when that text is recieved. Despite this the program will still not draw and I'm unsure on what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



//Represents the graphics display panel within the turtle program. This panel contains an image which is updated to reflect user commands.

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GraphicPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private int xPos = 0, yPos=0;
    private boolean penUp = true;
    private final static int DOWN = 0;
    private final static int UP = 1;
    private final static int LEFT = 2;
    private final static int RIGHT = 3;
    private int direction = DOWN;


GraphicPanel() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

    image = new BufferedImage(700, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the image.
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

    clear();

JTextField console = new JTextField(15);
    console.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                    if(console.getText().contains("penup")) {
                        penUp();
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("pendown")) {
                        penDown();
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("turnleft")) {
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "turnleft works");
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("turnright")) {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "turnright works");
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("forward")) {
                        forward(direction);
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("backward")) {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "backward works");
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("black")) {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "black works");
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("green")) {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "green works");
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("red")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "red works");
                    }

                    else if (console.getText().contains("reset")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "reset works");
                    }

                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "Invalid command, try again");
                    }
            }
    });

    add(console);
}

//private JTextField console = new JTextField(15);


//The default BG colour of the image.

private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;


 // The underlying image used for drawing. This is required so any previous drawing activity is persistent on the panel.

private BufferedImage image;

/*
 * Draw a line on the image using the given colour.
 * 
 * @param color
 * @param x1
 * @param y1
 * @param x2
 * @param y2
*/

// place pen onto canvas
public void penDown()
{
    penUp = false;
}

//raise pen from canvas
public void penUp()
{
    penUp = true;
}

// turn right from current position
public void turnRight()
{
    switch(direction)
    {
        case UP:
                direction = RIGHT;
                break;
        case DOWN:
                direction = LEFT;
                break;
        case LEFT:
                direction = UP;
                break;
        case RIGHT:
                direction = DOWN;
                break;
        default:
                break;

    }   
}

// turn left from current position
public void turnLeft()
{
    switch(direction)
    {
        case UP:
                direction = LEFT;
                break;
        case DOWN:
                direction = RIGHT;
                break;
        case LEFT:
                direction = DOWN;
                break;
        case RIGHT:
                direction = UP;
                break;
        default:
                break;

    }
}

// draw forward a certain amount
public void forward(int amount)
{

    if(penUp)
        return;

    if (direction == DOWN)
    {
        drawLine(Color.red, xPos, yPos, xPos, yPos + amount );
        yPos = yPos + amount;
    }

    else if (direction == UP)
    {
        drawLine(Color.red, xPos, yPos, xPos, yPos - amount );
        yPos = yPos - amount;
    }

    else if (direction == LEFT)     
    {
        drawLine(Color.red, xPos, yPos, xPos - amount, yPos );
        xPos = xPos - amount;
    }

    else if (direction == RIGHT)        
    {
        drawLine(Color.red, xPos, yPos, xPos + amount, yPos );
        xPos = xPos + amount;
    }

}

// draw backwards a certain amount
public void backward(int amount)
{
    if(penUp)
        return;

    if (direction == DOWN)
    {
        drawLine(Color.red, xPos, yPos, xPos, yPos - amount );
        yPos = yPos - amount;
    }

    else if (direction == UP)
    {
        drawLine(Color.red, xPos, yPos, xPos, yPos + amount );
        yPos = yPos + amount;
    }

    else if (direction == LEFT)     
    {
        drawLine(Color.red, xPos, yPos, xPos + amount, yPos );
        xPos = xPos + amount;
    }

    else if (direction == RIGHT)        
    {
        drawLine(Color.red, xPos, yPos, xPos - amount, yPos );
        xPos = xPos - amount;
    }
}

// change colour to black
public void black()
{
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
}

//change colour to green
public void green()
{
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.green);
}

// change colour to red
public void red()
{
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.red);
}

// draw lines to xy co-ordinates
public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(color);

    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

 //Clears the image contents.

public void clear() {

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);

    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(),  image.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    // render the image on the panel.
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}

 //Constructor.
```

}

Comment: Try to call `repaint()` on the `JPanel` after a command has been processed . Also, override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` .

Comment: I tried adding repaint() and still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this running but I had to take it apart and put it back together again.  Some things didn't make sense to me and it seems you wrote way too much code without having a working core.

I split the text input field out of the graphics panel and created an encompassing panel, TurtlePanel, to contain both of them.  I reworked the color logic and tweaked a number of things.  Some of the stuff I did was just to be able to run the example code standalone:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class TurtlePanel extends JPanel
{
    private GraphicPanel graphics = new GraphicPanel();
    private JTextField console = new JTextField(15);

    public TurtlePanel() {
        add(graphics);
        add(console);

        console.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                if (console.getText().contains("penup"))
                {
                    graphics.penUp();
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("pendown"))
                {
                    graphics.penDown();
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("turnleft"))
                {
                    graphics.turnLeft();
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("turnright"))
                {
                    graphics.turnRight();
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("forward"))
                {
                    graphics.forward(50);
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("backward"))
                {
                    graphics.backward(50);
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("black"))
                {
                    graphics.black();
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("green"))
                {
                    graphics.green();
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("red"))
                {
                    graphics.red();
                }
                else if (console.getText().contains("reset"))
                {
                    graphics.clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(console, "Invalid command, try again");
                }

                console.setText("");
                graphics.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TurtlePanel mainPanel = new TurtlePanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Testing Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class GraphicPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private int xPos = 400, yPos = 300;
    private boolean penUp = false;
    private Color color = Color.black;

    private BufferedImage image;
    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

    private enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }

    private Direction direction = Direction.DOWN;

    GraphicPanel() {

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        image = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));

        clear();
    }

    // place pen onto canvas
    public void penDown()
    {
        penUp = false;
    }

    // raise pen from canvas
    public void penUp()
    {
        penUp = true;
    }

    // turn right from current position
    public void turnRight()
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case UP:
                direction = Direction.RIGHT;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                direction = Direction.DOWN;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                direction = Direction.LEFT;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                direction = Direction.UP;
                break;
        }
    }

    // turn left from current position
    public void turnLeft()
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case UP:
                direction = Direction.LEFT;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                direction = Direction.DOWN;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                direction = Direction.RIGHT;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                direction = Direction.UP;
                break;
        }
    }

    // draw forward a certain amount
    public void forward(int amount)
    {
        if (penUp)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (direction)
        {
            case UP:
                drawLine(xPos, yPos, xPos, yPos - amount );
                yPos = yPos - amount;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                drawLine(xPos, yPos, xPos, yPos + amount );
                yPos = yPos + amount;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                drawLine(xPos, yPos, xPos - amount, yPos );
                xPos = xPos - amount;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                drawLine(xPos, yPos, xPos + amount, yPos );
                xPos = xPos + amount;
                break;
        }
    }

    // draw backwards a certain amount
    public void backward(int amount)
    {
        if (penUp)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (direction)
        {
            case UP:
                drawLine(xPos, yPos, xPos, yPos + amount );
                yPos = yPos + amount;
            case DOWN:
                drawLine(xPos, yPos, xPos, yPos - amount );
                yPos = yPos - amount;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                drawLine(xPos, yPos, xPos + amount, yPos );
                xPos = xPos + amount;
            case RIGHT:
                drawLine(xPos, yPos, xPos - amount, yPos );
                xPos = xPos - amount;
                break;
        }
    }

    // change colour to black
    public void black()
    {
        color = Color.black;
    }

    // change colour to green
    public void green()
    {
        color = Color.green;
    }

    // change colour to red
    public void red()
    {
        color = Color.red;
    }

    // draw lines to xy co-ordinates
    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    // Clears the image contents.
    public void clear() {

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        // render the image on the panel.
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

[image]